# QGIS Advanced Digitizing on drawing new feature with 60 degree angle

Tags: qgis, digitizing

[image: Long lines with short lines at 60 degree]

I am trying to draw a 60 degree line from the long line whenever I draw a long line regardless the angle of the long line.

But right now when I am using advanced digitizing tools and 90 degree means straight. I want the **90 degree to be my long line** so that I can easily draw short line at **60 degree.**

I am trying to figure up a method to do this few days and come out with nothing.

Comment: Once the 60 degrees is locked in (with the lock icon, or an 'a60[return]' keyboard entry, a capital "A" will toggle the angle constraint between the relative (marked with the 'Δ' icon in the sidebar, or a Δa in the "floater" window) and the absolute modes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it!

1. I will draw the long line manually and split the line using advanced digitalize toolbar to 2 parts to generate the starting point to transect the point.
   2)Select the feature you want to edit

[image: separated long line]
3) I will use Densify by intensity process (Which will help me to generate points along the line with a specific distance)

[image: Densify process]
4) Transect each points along the line using the transect process. (Which help me to generate the line at 60 degree to the left or right at each point along the line.)

[image]
5) Done

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use Advanced Digitizing panel to give relative polar coordinates to the previous line segment drawn.

1. Turn on Digitizing and Advanced Digitizing Toolbars
2. Start a new line (Add Line Feature from Digitizing Toolbar)
3. Activate Advanced Digitizing Panel using Triangle Ruler icon in Advanced digitizing Toolbar
4. Digitize the first two points (your long line)
5. Move the mouse to the Advance Digitizing Panel and input angle in field **a** and push lock icon
6. Now you can digitize point only on the 60 degree line relative to the previous one. (you can also use **d** field to give the distance is you know)

Here is a figure with the ordinal numbers of steps from list above.
[image]

Comment: Thank you! It helps a lot! :)